# AWS Lambda function using CognitoIdentityServiceProvider's adminCreateUser method is failing all of a sudden

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

In the past few days I've been testing a certain flow using AWS Lambda functions and my lambda function that gets triggered after a pre-sign up in the Cognito User pool was working fine and returning the callback function well. But since yesterday I've been seeing the following error:-

```
ntime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
2021-04-19T11:09:07.321Z    b42b6dd0-b290-454c-afa9-6be666903995    INFO    InvalidLambdaResponseException: Invalid lambda function output : Invalid JSON
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'InvalidLambdaResponseException',
  time: 2021-04-19T11:09:07.260Z,
  requestId: 'a52a10ae-efdf-4358-b6e0-8c6bbbc10f26',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 45.341053308762234
}
2021-04-19T11:09:07.508Z    b42b6dd0-b290-454c-afa9-6be666903995    INFO    InvalidLambdaResponseException: Invalid lambda function output : Invalid JSON
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'InvalidLambdaResponseException',
  time: 2021-04-19T11:09:07.260Z,
  requestId: 'a52a10ae-efdf-4358-b6e0-8c6bbbc10f26',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 48.61578358654741
} InvalidLambdaResponseException: Invalid lambda function output : Invalid JSON
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
END RequestId: b42b6dd0-b290-454c-afa9-6be666903995
REPORT RequestId: b42b6dd0-b290-454c-afa9-6be666903995  Duration: 2564.50 ms    Billed Duration: 2565 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 88 MB  Init Duration: 427.70 ms
```

This is the lambda function:-

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
    apiVersion: '2016-04-18'
});

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("Event input => ", event);

    const attributes = event.arguments;
    const userPoolId = process.env.USERPOOL_ID;

    var params = {
        UserPoolId: userPoolId,
        Username: attributes.username,
        DesiredDeliveryMediums: ["EMAIL"],
        UserAttributes: [{
                Name: "email",
                Value: attributes.email,
            },
            {
                Name: "email_verified" /* required */ ,
                Value: "true",
            },
            {
                Name: "name" /* required */ ,
                Value: attributes.name,
            }
        ]
    };


    try {
        const data = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider
            .adminCreateUser(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                    // an error occurred
                }
                else {
                    console.log("SUCCESS", JSON.stringify(data)); // successful response

                }
                callback(null, data);
            })
            .promise();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

This is the test event I'm using:-

```
{
  "arguments": {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "username": "jsmith",
    "email": "jsmith.com@gmail.com",
  }
}
```

I am not sure if I accidentally changed something in the code and don't remember or if something changed on AWS's side that is resulting in this. I have identified that the issue occurs when I am calling the adminCreateUser method from the try catch block. But can't figure out what specifically is resulting in the error from the error stack. Help would be appreciated!

**Update:-**

After spending plenty of hours trying to fix this and some of the other obscure errors while trying to build custom resolvers, I just ended up switching away from AWS AppSync and ended up building my own custom API with Django and Graphene-based GraphQL API that I hosted on Heroku. And it made a world of difference in the speed and customizability that I had in my hands. I would highly recommend looking into the Python-based FastAPI which is much more lightweight and super impressive, both in terms of performance (It's as fast as NodeJS!) and modernity. I will be using that as my GraphQL API for my upcoming projects.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57583289/why-does-my-aws-lambda-function-return-invalid-json-error

Comment: I saw that question and it is pretty much identical to what I'm facing. However, I am not sure how I can identify what AWS changed internally. How does one go about finding what changed within their event definition?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, any update?